# oracle database EM tools: Error java.lang.Exception: Exception in sending Request :: null

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I get following error on Enterprise Manager Errors on Oracle 10g2 .

***oracle database EM tools: Error   java.lang.Exception: Exception in sending Request :: null***

I need help to overcome this problem on my win8 pc

Answer (score 0):

Probably a firewall issue. Please try after disabling it for a moment!